# how let Buildbot pull changes from git repo by notice?

Tags: buildbot

Can anybody give a live example about this question , I followed all articles in Buildbot official sites, there is no live example there. what I want is quite simple, when a developer pushes code to git , the git server tells buildbot to pull changes and start building and deploy process.

Comment: Asking question without minimal code will be closed

Answer (score 0):

You need this:

http://docs.buildbot.net/0.8.8/manual/cfg-changesources.html#chsrc-PBChangeSource

"PBChangeSource actually listens on a TCP port for clients to connect and push change notices into the Buildmaster. This is used by the built-in buildbot sendchange notification tool, as well as several version-control hook scripts."